# Bayesian random effects

Tags: random-effects-model, hierarchical-bayesian

$\newcommand{\N}{\operatorname{N}}$$\newcommand{\IG}{\operatorname{IG}}$My understanding of bayesian random effects (I understand that this concept is a frequentist one, but I use it for simplicity) is that one could write down the following model:
$$Y_{ij} = X_{ij}\beta + Z_{ij}\alpha_{i} + \varepsilon_{ij} \,,$$ with: $$\begin{array}{rcl} \varepsilon_{ij} & \sim & \N(0, \sigma^2) \,, \\
\sigma^2 & \sim & \IG(\frac{\nu}{2},\frac{\nu}{2})\,, \\
\beta & \sim & \N(\beta_0, \Sigma_0)\,, \end{array} \quad\quad
\begin{array}{rcl} \alpha_i & \sim & \N(0, \tau)\,, \\
\tau & \sim & \IG(\alpha_0, \beta_0) \,, \end{array}$$
where $X_{ij}\beta$ is the "fixed effect" and $Z_{ij}\alpha_{i}$ is the "random effect". But $\sigma^2$ is the "within-group variance". And I believe $\tau$ is the "between-group variance".

That setup doesn't make intuitive sense to me though. Is it incorrect? What do we call $\Sigma_0$?  Can someone explain how the between/within group variability corresponds to the fixed and random effects?